# how to create a component that i can set fetching url data in an attribute in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a application with angular 2 , i want to create a component in angular 2 that I set URL in attribute and want use several times from this component and each component have own data...
i want something like this : 
its possible or not?

I'll really appreciate if someone help me.

```
new movies : 
<comp url="www.aaaa.com/movies?type=new"></comp>

old movies : 
<comp url="www.aaaa.com/movies?type=old"></comp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp',
  template: '<div>{{data}}</div>'
})
export class Component {
  @Input() url: string;
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    this.http.get(this.url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(val => this.data = val);
  } 
}
```

If the component has more than one input then you need to check which one was updated. See https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges for more details.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "each component". You can add as many instances of this component as you want. These instances work independently. You need to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` "somewhere" (for example at the root component of your Angular application. `@Component({ ..., providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS], ...})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use compoenent as mentioned above answer.
But for this kind of task I always choose directive. You can also create a directive which will take one parameter and do the stuff.

In this way you don't have to create a tag but in any tag you can apply your directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[comp]',
})
export class compDorective implements OnInit {
  @Input() url: string;
  constructor(private http:Http, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(changes) {
    this.http.get(this.url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(val => this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHtml = val);
  } 
}
```

you can apply this directive to any element like this

```
<div comp [url]="www.aaaa.com/movies?type=new"></div>
<span comp [url]="www.aaaa.com/movies?type=old"></span>
```